# Empty GameObject reset to 0,0,0 but now I can't move it with the childs of it since the arrows are far away at 0,0,0 anyway to change it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I make double click on the empty GameObject as it should be it's zooming to the children group :

[image: Npcs]

I grouped all the npcs under emprt GameObject name Npcs but first I was reseting Npcs to 0,0,0
Now the arrows of the axis to drag and change the Npcs positions are far away.
The idea was to easy move the npcs all the same time.

When I zoom out in the scene window this is where the Npcs is so if I will drag it and change it's positions I will not see where the npcs are moving to they are too far.

[image: Npcs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Header Menu has a [Toolbar](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html) where you can switch between two modes (briefly mentioned [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html))

[image]

- **`Pivot`** 
  Use the pivot position of the first selected GameObject
- **`Center`** 
  Use Geometrical Center of all selected and nested Meshes or center of all GameObject pivots if no meshes found

[image]